# Python Binary and Regular String Confusion

Tags: python

I am sure this is a fairly noob question, I have googled, and cannot find a straight answer, but I may be asking the wrong thing... I am trying to make an Out Of Box Configuration script, and all the questions that need answered are stored in a file called pass.ini. When i get user input from getstr (using curses) when it populates my files, they all have b'variable string' as their values. when I try to do a strip command, I get b'riable strin'. when I do a str(variable) it gets the same issue. I saw where b'<variable_string>' can be a sign that it was in bytecode instead of decoded. so I tried a decode command and that failed as 'str object has no attribute 'decode' I have it writing out via ConfigParser, and to a separate file just as a file.write. Right now everything is commented out, I am out of ideas.

Here is the info gathering module:

```
        wrapper(CommitChanges)
            curses.echo()
            stdscr.addstr(  8, 19,  config.CIP , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CIP = stdscr.getstr(  8, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr(  9, 19,  config.CSM , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CSM = stdscr.getstr( 9, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 10, 19,  config.CGW , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CGW = stdscr.getstr(10, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 11, 19,  config.CD1 , curses.color_pair(3) ) 
            config.CD1 = stdscr.getstr(11, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 12, 19,  config.CD2 , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CD2 = stdscr.getstr(12, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 13, 19,  config.CNTP, curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CNTP = stdscr.getstr(13, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 16, 19,  config.CHN , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CHN = stdscr.getstr(16, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 14, 19,  config.CID , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CID = stdscr.getstr(14, 19, 15)
            stdscr.addstr( 15, 19,  config.CS , curses.color_pair(3) )
            config.CS = stdscr.getstr(15, 19, 15)
```

This is the file output module

```
def CommitChanges():
    MOP = "X"
    Config['Array=all']['PTLIP']        = a
    Config['Array=all']['PTLSM']        = config.CSM.decode('utf-8')
    Config['Array=all']['PTLGW']        = config.CGW.decode('utf-8')  
    Config['Array=all']['PTLD1']        = config.CD1.decode('utf-8')
    Config['Array=all']['PTLD2']        = config.CD2.decode('utf-8') 
    Config['Array=all']['PTLNTP']       = config.CNTP.decode('utf-8') 
    Config['Array=all']['PTLIF']        = config.CIFN.decode('utf-8') 
    Config['Array=all']['PTLHSTNM']     = config.CHN.decode('utf-8') 
    Config['Array=all']['PTLMOB']       = config.CMOB.decode('utf-8')
    Config['Array=all']['customerid']   = config.CID.decode('utf-8')
    Config['Array=all']['site']         = config.CS.decode('utf-8')
    with open('/opt/passp/pass.ini', 'w') as passini:
        Config.write(passini, space_around_delimiters=False)
    tpass= open('./pass.b', 'w')
    tpass.write("[Array=All]"+ "\n")
    tpass.write("ptlip="+ a + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptlsm="+ config.CSM.decode('utf-8') +"\n")
    tpass.write("ptlgw="+ config.CGW.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptld1="+ config.CD1.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
        tpass.write("ptld2="+ config.CD2.decode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptlntp="+ config.CNTPdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptlif="+ config.CIFNdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptldhstnm="+ config.CHNdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("ptlmob="+ config.CMOBdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("customerid="+ config.CIDdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    tpass.write("site="+ config.CSdecode('utf-8') + "\n")
    #if Backupfiles():
    textchanges()
    return
```

Here is the file save output created by ConfigParser

```
[Array=all]
ptlip=b'123'
ptlsm=b'321'
ptlgw=b'111'
ptld1=b'222'
ptld2=b'333'
ptlntp=b'444'
ptlif=s19
ptlhstnm=b'555'
ptlmob=
customerid=b'666'
site=b'777'
```

It perfectly matches when I do a direct write (they were from two different runs, but even with empty data it has the wrapper.

Interesting notice here, 'ptlif' is gathered from finding the interface name, it isn't handled by user input, so it has to be how the config.XXXX variables are stored.

```
[Array=All]
ptlip=b''
ptlsm=b''
ptlgw=b''
ptld1=b''
ptld2=b''
ptlntp=b''
ptlif=s19
ptldhstnm=b''
ptlmob=
customerid=b''
site=b''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what my problem was.

ncurses getstr returns a binary value, and I was sending it to a string literal variable.

I created a new set of variables, set them up as

```
cipb = b'foo'
cipb = stdscr.getstr( y, x, len )
config.CIP = cipb.decode()
```

That fixed it.  Hopefully this might help someone else out with a similar issue.